# How can I configure netbeans for adding logger into new class by default

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I configure netbeans for adding logger into my new java class by default while creating new ones?
I can get my logger by default by typing code template : **log** 
But this gives me instant : `Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "");` and after some time my class becomes full of this `Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName())` which should be replaced by a simple `LOG` with a :
`private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());` at the top of the class which I get after right clicking class -> Insert code -> Logger

Can I get this automatically added while creating new classes?